# Powershell regex to replace a specific character between two identical characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to use Powershell to replace a semicolon `;` with a pipe `|` that is in a file that is semicolon separated, so it's a specific set of semicolons that occurs between double-quotes `"`. Here's a sample of the file with the specific portion in bold:

> Camp;Brazil;AI;BCS GRU;;MIL-32011257;172-43333640;;**"1975995;1972871;1975"**;FAC0088/21;3;20.000;24.8;25.000;.149;GLASSES SPARE PARTS,;EXW;C;.00;EUR;

I've tried using `-replace`, as follows:

```
(Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace '".*(;).*"',"|" } |
```

However, the regex does not replace the semicolon between the quotes with a pipe. I've tried several other Regex to no avail. What would I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_) method with a callback as the replacement argument:

```
$s = 'Camp;Brazil;AI;BCS GRU;;MIL-32011257;172-43333640;;"1975995;1972871;1975";FAC0088/21;3;20.000;24.8;25.000;.149;GLASSES SPARE PARTS,;EXW;C;.00;EUR;'
$rx = [regex]'"[^"]*"'
$rx.Replace($s, { param($m) $m.value.Replace(';','|') })
# => Camp;Brazil;AI;BCS GRU;;MIL-32011257;172-43333640;;"1975995|1972871|1975";FAC0088/21;3;20.000;24.8;25.000;.149;GLASSES SPARE PARTS,;EXW;C;.00;EUR;
```

That is, match any substring between two `"` chars, and replace all `;` chars with `|` inside the matches only.

Also, here is PowerShell Core v6.1+ version where you can pass a *script block* as the `-replace` replacement operand where the match is represented as an automatic `$_` variable:

```
(Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace '"[^"]*"', { $_.Value.Replace(';', '|') } }
```

**Why not use lookarounds?**

Since the left- and right-hand delimiters are *identical single chars*, `"`, any lookaround-based solution will either be erroneous or too long and still prone to errors. It would happen because lookarounds do not consume the texts they match, and each `"` thus could be matched separately as the initial `"`. Have a  look at the `(?<="[^"]*);(?=[^"]*")` [regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%29%3b%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%22%5d*%22%29&i=a%3b%22b%3bc%3bd%22%3b1%3b23%3b%2245%3b677777%3bz%22%3b+end%3b+of+%3b+text&r=%7c), where `"b;c;d";1;23;"45;677777;z"` turns into `"b|c|d"|1|23|"45|677777|z"` because the `;` between `1` and `23`, and `23` and `"` are found between two double quotation marks.

Similar problem is also with the `\G`-based patterns that can be used to match multiple match occurrences between two *different* delimiters, and that are usually not used in .NET regex as the latter supports infinite-width lookbehinds.

Comment: Very interesting. Hadn’t seen this technique before.

Comment: Wiktor, thanks for the help. I'm upgrading to PowerShell 6.1 or newer to get that functionality.